# Eclipse Can't Find MinGW/Can't setup C++ on Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I am trying to setup c++ in Eclipse IDE. I have installed the C++ Development Tools and C++ Development Tools SDK. I have read "Before you begin" in "C/C++ Development Guide". I have installed MinGW on the page it provides. It installes it to C:\MinGW which Eclipse said it could recognize. I create a new makefile C++ project with MinGW selected as my tool chain. I had to uncheck "Show toolchains only if they are supported on the platform". It doesn't work. I have spent hours on trying to make this work.[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Looks like Eclipse isn't looking for gcc/g++ in the right place. You should tell Eclipse where to find these executable files of the MinGW GCC toolchain.

Comment: Well I set it to C:\MinGW where the program installed it, but it contains different folders which I guess could be the correct one. So if you see the correct one please let me know (I'll add a picture of the directories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Eclipse where to `gcc.exe` and `g++.exe`.
In your case I would expect that to be `C:\MinGw\mingw32\bin` or `C:\MinGw\bin`.

If there's no `gcc.exe` and `g++.exe` there, it would appear your MinGW setup is broken.

Note that plain MinGW is a not very well maintained or up to date. I would recommend switching to MinGW-w64, which exists for both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit. A standalone build for Windows of recent MinGW-w64 can be downloaded from https://winlibs.com/. Just extract the file (no installer needed) and point to the `mingw32\bin` or `mingw64\bin` folder to find the compiler toolchain.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up adding gcc and g++ in the cataloge and Eclipse automatically recognized it.